# How to display the subject and room name according to the particular day and period in a time-table?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 6 days from monday to saturday. But I have stored only 3 days periods in database.
I got those things in the array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subject] => 17
            [room] => 3
            [period] => 1
            [day] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subject] => 8
            [room] => 2
            [period] => 1
            [day] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [subject] => 10
            [room] => 1
            [period] => 1
            [day] => 5
        )

.....
```

Now I need to display this in the view. If I have subject in the particular period, I want to display that, else all subjects should display.

my ctp file content:

```
 1. <table id="ss" style="border:1px solid #cccccc" class="form_text">
            <tr style="background: url('<?php echo $this->webroot;?>img/title.gif') repeat-x; height:20px">
                <td align="center" style="width:1%"><strong>Days</strong></td>

            <?php foreach($period_num as $k) : ?>

            <td align="center" style="width:2%"><strong><?php echo $k    ?></strong></td>
          <?php endforeach ?>               


            </tr>
          <?php for($i=0; $i<6; $i++) : ?> <?php


                          if ( ( $i % 2) == 0 ) 

                              $bg_color = "#efefef";

                          else

                               $bg_color = "#FFF"; ?>       <tr  style="background: <?php echo $bg_color; ?>">          <?php      
    $total=count($period_num);?>            <?php for($j=0; $j<=$total; $j++) : 
    ?>          <?php $index = $i*$total+$j-1 ?>
                          <?php $count=0; ?>

            <td>            <?php if($j==0) : ?>

                    <?php echo $workingDays[$i]['Day']['day_name'] ?> 
                    <?php elseif($j!=0 && $subject==0): ?>

                     <?php echo $form->hidden('ClassSchedule.'.$index.'.day_id',
                                             array('value'=>$workingDays[$i]['Day']['day_id'],

                                            'style' => 'width: 35%;'));?>
                    <?php echo $form->hidden('ClassSchedule.'.$index.'.period_name',
                                             array('value'=>$j,

                                            'style' => 'width: 35%;')); 
                      ?>
                    <?php echo $form->input('ClassSchedule.'.$index.'.subject_id', array('options'=>$subject_sel,'empty'=>'none')) ?>
                    <?php echo $form->input('ClassSchedule.'.$index.'.room_id', array('options'=>$room_sel,'empty'=>'none')) ?>
                          <?php else:?>
                                     <?php echo $form->hidden('ClassSchedule.'.$index.'.day_id',
                                             array('value'=>$workingDays[$i]['Day']['day_id'],

                                            'style' => 'width: 35%;'));?>
                    <?php echo $form->hidden('ClassSchedule.'.$index.'.period_name',
                                             array('value'=>$j,

                                            'style' => 'width: 35%;')); ?>

                                    <?php echo $form->input('ClassSchedule.'.$index.'.subject_id',      
    array('options'=>$subject_sel)) ?>
                    <?php echo $form->input('ClassSchedule.'.$index.'.room_id', array('options'=>$room_sel)) ?>             <?php endif ?>
                                    <?php endfor ?> </td> <?php $count++; ?>    </tr> <?php endfor ?> </table> <?php } ?>
          <?php echo $form->end();?>
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of the desired outcome?

Comment: Please add more information in your question about your requirement. Your requirement can be translated in to simple if/else, while, etc statements, but only **IF** you explain it in more clear manner. Show us your desired output. An example of what you want to display.

Comment: im designing a time table for a class. from monday to saturday. i ve only 1 period in all 6 days. but the subjects for all periods are different. i want to display those subjects in the respective period on the respective day. the array i ve shown above is the output i got from controller. how to change those id's into names and display in  the view???

Comment: No, dont explain here in comments, Click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11792866/edit) link. What we want is that you tell us like "Output I want is `<table><tr><td>Period</td><td>Subject</td></tr><tr><td>Science</td><td>1</td>...` Of course it is just an example. Please show us your Desired Output in Static HTML.